# CherryPy wsgi basic http authentication

Tags: python, cherrypy, basic-authentication

Is it possible to use the methods of `cherrypy.lib.auth_basic` for a `CherryPyWSGIServer` object?

Even if I call the `cherrypy.config.update` function for including the list of permitted users, clients can still access and use the application without any authentication credential.

```
    from soaplib.core import Application
    from cherrypy import wsgiserver
    import cherrypy
    from cherrypy.wsgiserver import CherryPyWSGIServer

    userpassdict = {'bird' : 'bebop', 'ornette' : 'wayout'}
    checkpassword = cherrypy.lib.auth_basic.checkpassword_dict(userpassdict)
    basic_auth = {'tools.auth_basic.on': True,
                    'tools.auth_basic.realm': 'earth',
                    'tools.auth_basic.checkpassword': checkpassword,
    }
    app_config = { '/' : basic_auth }
    cherrypy.config.update(app_config)

    #initialize service
    soap_app = Application([MySoapMethods], tns, app_name);
    wsgi_app = cherrypy.Application(soap_app);
    server = wsgiserver.CherryPyWSGIServer((server_addr, server_port), wsgi_app);
    server.start()
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't work"?  More information will help those answering the question pinpoint the problem.

Comment: clients can access and use the application without any authentication credentials

Comment: Okay, you should incorporate that into the question, then.  Regrettably, I don't have an answer for you, but having as much info as possible will be helpful to the person who does.